# Couldn't connect Springboot project to Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, api, localhost

When I run the  SpringBoot application in **Workspace-Spring-Tool-Suite** Mysql Workbench generate all the tables But a **Get** request in **Postman** (http://localhost:3308/api/v1/employees) does not return anything but an error  (Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http)

- Mysql Xampp is Running on port: 3308

**UPDATE**  now the connection is working and generating tables on MYSQL workbench but the localhost's  problem still exists it returns
**ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE**
The WORST is a new problem while running SpringBoot App:**ERROR**

Description:
Web server failed to start. Port 3308 was already in use.
Action:
Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 3308 or configure this application to listen on another port.

NB: I didn't use port 3308 for any other service.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/employee_management_system? 
 useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
server.port=3308
```

**Controller class**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.controller;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;
import net.javaguides.springboot.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3308")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

// get all employees
@GetMapping("/employees")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
    return employeeRepository.findAll();
}       }
```

**Running Springboot Application**
 [Running Spring-Boot application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klByT.png)

**Employee Class**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "email_id")
private String emailId;

public Employee() {
    
}

public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String emailId) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}}
```

**Employee Repository Class**

```
package net.javaguides.springboot.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import net.javaguides.springboot.model.Employee;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{ }
```

Comment: As I see, this is not a connection error, can you show more Employee class and EmployeeRepository class?

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3308")
```

by

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

and use a different port for your application rather than the same port used for accessing your DB

```
server.port=8081
```

Comment: Thanks..It works when I changed port:  8082                                                                                             CONCLUSION: Springboot and Xampp shouldn't be running on the same port